# Find how much a signal curves in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, curve

I already asked this question in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690430/how-to-define-the-curvature-of-a-function-in-simulink/1690441?noredirect=1#comment3450564_1690441), i have a random signal, like the one in the following image :

[image: Input Signal]

i need a way in Simulink, that takes as **input the signal in the image**, and it gives me as an output a **signal with an amplitude proportional to how much the input signal curves** ?

**EDIT :**

[image: Model]

I have the input signal in my workspace under the name : **expo**, i use a **from workdpace** block to export it, i take it through the **first derivative** and than **second derivative** and also an **integrator** (i used a saturation block to limit the pics), here are the results :

1. FIRST DERIVATIVE SCOPE :
   [image: 1st Deriv]
   .
2. SECOND DERIVATIVE SCOPE :
   [image: 2nd Deriv]
   .
3. INTEGRATOR SCOPE :
   [image: Integrator]
   .

Comment: I already made a suggestion to solve it. Please show what you have tried and why it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @Daniel , here is what i did, am i doing it Right ?

Comment: Looks right, what seems wrong to you?

Comment: It was right actually, Yeah now i get it, unfortunately it was not what i was looking for, i signal i need to build wasn't the curving signal, I'm out of ideas, Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Just realized you used the continuous derivative for a probably discrete signal. Maybe choose the discrete derivative to remove some of the aliasing (the shaded areas). You could try to describe what signal you expected instead.

Comment: Actually even if i do that, i don't think it's what i need to complete my idea, I'm kinda lost here, and it's not something we can talk about on a forum, too bad there is no private messaging in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105999/discussion-between-carter-nolan-and-daniel).